# Should pika's channel.basic_publish timeout sooner if there is no network connection?

Tags: pika, python-pika

I'm in the process of upgrading to pika 1.1.0, and performed some sanity testing.
I have:

- placed a breakpoint at the following
- **disconnected the network**
- stepped over this command

... and no exception was thrown. Is this expected?

```
        channel.basic_publish(
            exchange=EXCHANGE,
            routing_key=ROUTING_KEY, 
            body=message,
            properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                delivery_mode=MQ_TRANSIENT_DELIVERY_MODE,
                headers=headers,
            )
        )
```

The connection is created with:

```
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host=rabbit_config.host,
        credentials=credentials,
        port=rabbit_config.port,
        connection_attempts=1,
        blocked_connection_timeout=10,
        retry_delay=5,
        socket_timeout=20,
        heartbeat=30,     ))
```

**update**:
If I call `channel.confirm_delivery()` before this, I successfully get a AMQPError.

However, this doesn't happen for 60 seconds (which doesn't my ConnectionParameters). How can I have it notice the connection loss quicker?

Comment: If you step over `basic_publish` how do you expect the client to know the network is disconnected? "step over" means that `channel.basic_publish` was **not** executed.

Comment: If I perform a socket write , the socket can timeout if it does not receive a TCP ack. That timeout parameter should be utilized